# How to Toggle SpeakerPhone during Call on Android 13 using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

whay does this does not work on Android 13 using Xamarin.Forms

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
                {
                    IList<AudioDeviceInfo> devices =                                   MainActivity.audioManager.AvailableCommunicationDevices;
                    foreach (AudioDeviceInfo device in devices)
                    {
                        if (device.Type == AudioDeviceType.BuiltinSpeaker)
                        {
                            Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                            { var IsItTrue =        MainActivity.audioManager.SetCommunicationDevice(device); });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

this has been reported as a bug report with Google

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/279105862

this is several year old bug but no one has posted a working solution and Bug Report site is not responding to my status request.

Comment: This is not a forum for determining why some bug has not been corrected.  The correct avenue to address that, would be the bug report itself, and any information you can find within it for support persons, support avenues and the like.  StackOverflow is not a bug management system. nor is it support for any OS, Platform, or app, et cetera.

Comment: How do I get a latest working solution for this question using Xamarin?

Comment: This page tells about support options for xamarin: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin